# Evaluate the integral $ \int _{\vert z \vert =1} \frac{1}{\sin(e^{-1/z})}\,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

> Evaluate the integral
>   $$\int _{\vert z \vert =1} \frac{1}{\sin(e^{-1/z})}\,dz.$$

I tried using Laurent series but not getting result. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

After letting $w=-1/z$, by the Residue Theorem,
$$\begin{align}
\int _{|z| =1} \frac{1}{\sin(e^{-1/z})}\,dz
&=-\int _{|w |=1} \frac{1}{\sin(e^{w})}\cdot \frac{dw}{w^2}\\
&=
-2\pi i\,\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{w^2 \sin(e^{w})},0\right)\\
&=-2\pi i \frac{d}{dw}\left(\frac{1}{\sin(e^{w})}\right)_{w=0}\\
&= \frac{2\pi i\cos(1)}{\sin^2(1)}.
\end{align}$$
P.S. Note that $\sin(e^{w})=0$ iff $e^w=n\pi$, but $0<|e^w|\leq e<\pi$ for $|w|\leq 1$.

Comment: Every number of the form $-\frac1{\log(n\pi)}$ ($n\in\mathbb N$) is a singularity of $f$.

Comment: Ouch! You are right. Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, very much so.